# How to return results from Azure Search order by values of a given field

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

below is a example of the search results returned from Azure Search after searching for  everything in the gift department (**default**)

```
   {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "trousers",
        "department": "gift",
        "description": "This is the description of the item"
    }
    {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "toy",
        "department": "gift",
        "description": "This is the description of the item"
    }
    {
        "id": "3",
        "type": "shirt",
        "department": "gift",
        "description": "This is the description of the item"
    }
```

The result set required should be ordered by type in this order- **toy**,**shirt**,**trousers**. As you can see the result is not a simple orderby "type" field asc/desc. the expected result should be

```
  {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "toy",
        "department": "gift",
        "description": "This is the description of the item"
    }

  {
        "id": "3",
        "type": "shirt",
        "department": "gift",
        "description": "This is the description of the item"
    }

   {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "trousers",
        "department": "gift",
        "description": "This is the description of the item"
    }
```

How do i go about doing this - written descriptions and/or code snippets would be fine?

Comment: Are you using any SDK for searching? Please share the code you’ve written.

Comment: Yes i'm using the SDK. Everything is working fine just need to work out how to sort the data returned. I'm not able to share the code as its sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using .Net SDK for performing the search, you can use [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchparameters.orderby?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Search_Models_SearchParameters_OrderBy) property of [`SearchParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchparameters?view=azure-dotnet) to define the ordering criteria.

Assuming your `type` field is sortable, you can try something like:

```
var searchParameters = new SearchParameters();
searchParameters.OrderBy = new List<string>()
{
  "type desc"
};
```

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect that the sort is not alphabetical. the sort should be in this order  - toy,shirt,trousers

Comment: Ordering only works ascending/descending so it will not work in your scenario. One possible solution would be to define an additional field that is used explicitly for ordering your search results.